# Looping arrays: Object variable or with block not set, Property or method not supported, etc

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to grab multiple pieces of info from one Excel workbook(1) and plug them into certain cells in another Excel workbook(2) by using Select Case. I used an array to store the info from Excel workbook(1) and then wanted to loop the array to plug in the different values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click() 
Dim MyArray(2 To 6) As Range, Time As Single, Description As String
MyArray(2) = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").Range("C2")
MyArray(3) = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").Range("C3")
MyArray(4) = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").Range("C4")
MyArray(5) = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").Range("C5")
MyArray(6) = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").Range("C6")

Time = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").MyArray(2, 6).Offset(0, 3).value

Description = Workbooks("case_time_report.xlsm").Worksheets("case_time_report.csv").MyArray(2, 6).Offset(0, 8).value

For i = 2 To UBound(MyArray)
        Select Case MyArray(i).text
        Case "Correspondence"
             Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 18) = Time
             Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
        Case "VTC"
             Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 14) = Time
               Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
     Case "Travel"
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 17) = Time
               Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
       Case "Telephone Call"
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 18) = Time
               Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
       Case "Client Meeting"
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 14) = Time
             Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
        Case "Court Hearing"
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 5) = Time
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
      Case "Motions"
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 16) = Time
              Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Description
            End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

I keep getting problems like "Object variable or with block not set" and "Property or method not supported".

Comment: `MyArray(2)` and `MyArray(6)` get populated with the same value (from cell C2). Is that intentional or should `MyArray(6)` be populated from cell C6 instead?

Comment: Yeah thanks for catching that! It should populate info from C6

Answer (score 0):

You have several very minor syntax issues you need to fix first:

- You **Dim** *MyArray()* as a one-dimensional array, but use it as a two-dimensional array.
- Use `MyArray(i)` rather then `MyArray(i).text`

Comment: How can I Dim it as a two-dimensional array? Are there any other problems that are relatively easy fixes that I'm missing? Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @AndrewZavala  I only mentioned the issues I could see without testing